# Usage of 'if' in two sentences

Tags: grammar, conditionals

> 'It may be wondered if the scope is too wide.'
>   'It may be wondered if the scope is not too wide.'

Do these two sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes, in almost any credible context, they would mean exactly the same. Think of the second version as a shortening of constructions such as *One might wonder **if it is not the case** that X is true.* Have a look at some written instances of [*I **shouldn't** wonder if you **weren't** (whatever I think you probably **are**)*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22i+shouldn%27t+wonder+if+you+weren%27t%22)

Comment: It is really only the same as comparing "I wonder if it will be too big", with "I wonder if it will not be too big". The latter is merely an idiomatic way of saying the former. But it doesn't work in all cases. "I wonder if it's big enough" does not convert to "I wonder if it's not big enough". Unless you are a native speaker you are likely to find English idioms infuriatingly inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes,

like FumbleFingers mentioned above, such pairs have the same meaning. In this case, they both mean that *a knowledgable and impartial judge could easily think that the scope of Foo is too wide*.

It seems odd that two conditional sentences whose [protases](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protases#English) are opposites are actually equivalent.

However, in these two sentences, you don't mean that

> We can wonder in the future about some other unknown thing **if and only if** we discover that the scope of Foo is too wide.

What you actually mean is that

> It is already reasonable to wonder “Is the scope of Foo too wide?”

The questions “Am I too late?” and “Am I not too late?” are effectively synonyms, because **the real information that people want is the same in both cases**: in both cases, the questioners want to know if they are still early enough to do something or if they missed their chance.

They're not complete synonyms. The second way of asking is a little more hopeful, although still nervously focused on the lateness. The answers “yes” or “no” would mean opposite things in either case. Still, you shouldn’t answer negative questions in English with a yes or no in the first place: it’s much clearer and more helpful to give an full answer like “You still have 5 minutes” or, “Sorry, he already left.”

**In your example**, the question is being talked about abstractly and there’s no possibility at all of a short answer causing any confusion. Thus, they’re effectively synonyms. Either one should be followed with additional information and reasoning that irrefutably establishes how the scope of Foo is in fact **not** too broad, bringing the nay-sayers into the writer's camp.